# Collar neighborhood theorem for manifold with corners

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, manifolds

I was reading this wonderful sequence of posts:
[nlab: *manifold with boundary*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/manifold+with+boundary)
and [nlab: *collar neighbourhood theorem*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/collar+neighbourhood+theorem)
and I couldn't help but wonder.  Is there an extension of the [Collar neighborhood Theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970177) for manifolds with corners; in the sense that if $X$ is a $d$-dimensional manifold with corners then the set $X_0$ of points $x \in X$ with no neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$ has a neighborhood $U_{X_0}$ which is homeomorphic to $X_0\times [0,1)$ such that this homomorphism maps $X_0$ to $X_0\times \{0\}$?

*Edit:* @MoisheKohan both solved and refined my initial formulation.  Here is the updated version which I initially hoped to express:

Does there exist such a $U_{X_0}$ which is isomorphic to $X_0\times [0,1)$ as manifolds with corners?

Comment: This recent question [MO385911](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385911) seems to be related, but at a higher level of generality.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I'm not sure how to interpret that thread's answer in this context..

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert who could just say that one follows from another. However, I see the following similarities: (1) stratified spaces generalize manifolds with boundaries and corners; (2) the boundary is the closure of the codimension-1 stratum; (3) a collar neighborhood is a special case of contractible neighborhood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extended comment.

The way your question is stated, the answer is
"yes," of course. Each (topological) manifold with corners is also a manifold with boundary. Your subset $X_0$ is just the boundary. Now, the claim follows from the existence of a collar neighborhood of the boundary.

There is a more refined version of your question where instead of treating $X_0$ as a topological space, you treat it as a  manifold with corners. Then $U=U_{X_0}$ is also a **stratified** manifold <s>with corners</s>, where each stratum is a manifold with corners, and so is $X_0\times [0,1)$. The refined question is then if there exists $U$ such that the manifolds with corners $U$ and $X_0\times [0,1)$ are isomorphic in the category of **stratified** topological manifolds <s>with corners</s>. <s>I am quite sure that the answer to this one is also positive and is proven by imitating the standard argument for the existence of a collar neighborhood. But I did not think about the details since it is unclear if this is what you want to know.</s> With the naive (product) stratification of the product space, such an isomorphism of stratified manifolds fails. I will have to think if there is a reasonable modification of the product stratification under which one still has an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the updated post

Comment: @AIM_BLB: I concluded that the only way to get an isomorphism is the trivial one: In the product of the stratified spaces $X_0\times [0,1)$ retain just the strata in $X_0\times 0$ and declare the rest a single stratum.